# The sidebar is a not displaying in dashboard. I'm using bootstrap v4.6 with JQuery v1.10.2, Its working fine in all the Browsers except IE 11

Tags: bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11, sidebar, jquery-1.3, metismenu

Dashboard

onclick="navigate('${MAINMODULE['MODULENAME']}','${MAINMODULE['MODULECODE']}','${MAINMODULE['MODULEURL']}','${MAINMODULE['ISMULTIPLE']}')" >  ${MAINMODULE['MODULENAME']}
                             0 }">
                                
                                         
                        
                         0 }">

${SUBMODULE['MODULENAME']}

Comment: I would suggest you share a sample code that could help us test the issue with the IE 11 browser. Without code, it is hard to tell the cause. Further, check whether you are getting any errors in the developer tools. If there are errors, share those errors here. It might give an idea about the issue. Check whether other JS code is working on IE 11. If not, try to check whether JS is enabled in the IE browser.

Comment: Further, I would suggest upgrading the Jquery version as Jquery V1.10.2 is too old.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding code

Comment: The above-posted code is not giving an idea regarding the cause, I would suggest you post the sample that we could run in the IE 11 browser. It could help us check whether something is unsupported or whether there are any errors.

Comment: Starting June 15, 2022, the Internet Explorer 11 desktop application will no longer be supported on certain versions of Windows 10*. Due to this reason, I would suggest you could recommend your site users to move to Microsoft Edge browser. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/internet-explorer-11-end-of-support)